How to optimize code for incremental search inside grid control with millions of records?
I have windows form app using C#. I need to do incremental search inside the grid control from a text box. The problem when I type few letters the app hangup for 6 seconds until it display what I wrote and filter the grid. Currently there are 3 million records. Is there a way to make incremental search faster ?
I use this code to filter the result in a grid:
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchValue = textBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
        {
            dataGrid1.DataSource = dataTable;
        }
        else
        {
            var filteredRows = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(row => row.ItemArray.Any(
                    field => field.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchValue)));

            if (filteredRows.Any())
            {
                dataGrid1.DataSource = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
            }
            else
            {
                dataGrid1.DataSource = dataTable.Clone(); // No matches, clear grid
            }
            
           
        }
    }

Update:
I tried this and the result time was shorter but still not filter the grid in real time
(dataGrid1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter= string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", searchValue);


I don't know, but field.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchValue) is inefficient, do field.ToString().IndexOf(searchValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 instead.

@shingo: in what way is that a duplicate or at least helps OP to solve the performance issue? Using Rowfilter is even slower, less readable and maintainable. It's also not clear how that shows how use a substring search(what OP needs). RowFilter actually supports it(using like and %), but it's not better than what OP has anyway.

@Charlieface: good point, added to my answer

@TimSchmelter Can you clarify on why you think using Rowfilter is even slower, less readable and maintainable, since I can find many answers on SO that suggest to use RowFilter?

Tried now all the answers I still get lag while typing search letters and grid display the result.

@zac: What means "lag", did my answer improve the situation? How long it takes now to search with Contains in your 3 million rows? Are you sure that the time is consumed here and not where you fill the big table?

Calling filteredRows.Any() starts the enumerable running. If your search has to hit a million or so records before it gets a hit then the filteredRows.CopyToDataTable() call starts again. Using a .ToList() might just the time down significantly. And the .ToString().ToLower() is also a big cost.

@zac: just noticed that my answer was using the wrong code in the catch. Of course there was not need to use Any anymore, as that is what i wanted to avoid ;-) Fixed it now. Please try again

@TimSchmelter yes I measure the time from start typing. Time is shorter like 4 seconds until I see what I type and the result in the grid.

You have to measure the time in textBox1_TextChanged. So you used my (edited) code and it takes now 2 seconds instead of 6 before? You updated your question: "still not filter the grid in real time". So you expect that it doesn't take any time at all to search something in your 3 million record DataTable which is actually  very, very big? You should really consider to use a database which is optimized for searching.

@shingo: the RowFilter exists because the DataTable is one of the oldest classes in the NET framework, since .NET Framework 1.1 There we didn't have LINQ. It's kind of workaround for   it and it was a nice feature to support a limited set of filters for the in memory DataTable/DataView. But it is very limited, not very readable and maintainable and it's uses slow and ugly code to provide this feature(just have a look in the decompiled code). I'd always prefer LINQ for clean code. I don't want to use pseudo sql code with magic strings if i can use strongly typed code nowadays.

Maybe it would be best to not use a DataTable but a data base here, but that is out of scope.
So first optimization of your code would be to avoid the filteredRows.Any()-check, even if it's necessary because you otherwise get an InvalidOperationException at CopyToDataTable. The problem is that the Any already searches in your 3 million rows, also not that ItemArray creates a new object[] for every row's fields, so it's a memory intensive way.
You can use a different approach that avoids both by using try...catch and columns.Any and also uses String.Contains with the overload that supports a case insensitive comparison:
DataColumn[] allColumns = dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray();
var filteredRows = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => allColumns
        .Any(c => row[c].ToString()?.ToLower().IndexOf(searchValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));

try
{
    dataGrid1.DataSource = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    dataGrid1.DataSource = dataTable.Clone(); // No matches, clear grid
}

